# Good freeware for flowcharts on Windows?

Tags: flowchart

I have to present some 'process' or 'flow' of the application at work on friday. I was hoping to prepare a flow chart before I begin the hands on demo.

Any suggestions for freeware sw to make simple flowcharts on Windows?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Dia](http://live.gnome.org/Dia) might be worth looking at.

> It can be used to draw many different kinds of diagrams. It currently
>   has special objects to help draw entity relationship diagrams, UML
>   diagrams, flowcharts, network diagrams, and many other diagrams. It is
>   also possible to add support for new shapes by writing simple XML
>   files, using a subset of SVG to draw the shape.

Here is a [download page](http://dia-installer.de/).

Comment: that is for gnome. Here is the link for windows http://dia-installer.de/

Answer (score 28):

Tried [yEd](http://www.yworks.com/en/index.html) after finding this thread.  It's brilliant.  Nothing better, for free.

Comment: Yed is great for flowcharts, especially larger ones. The overview window lets you pan around the diagram and the zoom is very smooth

Comment: I just tried it. Very nice! You can even search for new symbols on-line and import them. Also, very clean and intuitive UI.

Comment: +1 Never heard of yEd before and it looks good.

Comment: @Scott I think this is no longer free as each download is an evaluation : http://www.yworks.com/en/downloads.html

Comment: @Adrian No - yEd is still free and this never changed: "[Can I use yEd for free? Even for commercial purpose?](http://yed.yworks.com/support/qa/8)" - The *underlying* software libraries are available commercially.

Comment: yEd is really the way to go. I'm amazed it is free.

Answer (score 9):

I used [draw.io](https://www.draw.io) and it is very good.

Comment: 6,000 euros for a 1-developer license != freeware.

Comment: @Joe White: I used this link: http://www.mxgraph.com/demo/jgraphx/jgraphx.jnlp - I created a diagram and could save it and exported it in different formats. For free.

Comment: @JoeWhite https://github.com/jgraph/draw.io

Answer (score 7):

Use [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/).  At its core, it's a description language that produces decent graphcs automatically.  Another answer recommended Dia... Dia is a GUI tool that produces GraphViz .dot files.  If you want total layout control (generally not necessary for a flowchart), use Dia.  If you just want something that produces a reasonable layout by itself, use GraphViz directly.

As an added bonus, GraphViz works with many wiki packages as a plugin... Confluence, MediWiki, Trac, for starters.

Answer (score 7):

[Lovely Charts](http://www.lovelycharts.com/)- online solution.

Comment: Original question was regarding free ware. (i.e. Software which is "free") The link you posted is to software that you are charged for.

Answer (score 6):

[Google Drawings](http://google.com/google-d-s/drawings/) has been released since this question was answered. It has several built-in flowchart stencils, or check out the templates to find some more elaborate flowchart elements that you can copy-paste into your document.

Answer (score 6):

[code2flow](http://code2flow.com) is an online pseudo-code to flowchart generator, just click on the image to play with it:

[image: code2flow]

Answer (score 3):

[Bizagi](http://www.bizagi.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=95&Itemid=107&lang=en) Process Modeler is a freeware that is quite feature rich. Only for Windows

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

http://www.nchsoftware.com/chart/

simple ... free ... less than 1MB in size. It does the job well. I enjoyed it. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Microsoft Word or Excel you can select Insert|Shapes|Flowchart to create a Flowchart. I know it is not free but if you have Microsoft Office already, it may be an option.